# VBA UCase Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

Why on earth am I getting a type mismatch here?  When I type "january" into the input box I am getting a type mismatch immediately after.  Everything is a string(?).

```
Sub Test()

Dim sMonthOfMaintenance As String
Dim sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber As String

    sMonthOfMaintenance = InputBox("What month are you reviewing?")

    If UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JANUARY" Or "JAN" Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "01"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: While not your direct question - look at `Select Case` as an easy way to deal with the 12 months rather than a series of `If` statements. (e.g. `Select Case UCase(sMonthofMaintenance)` followed by statements like `Case "JANUARY", "JAN"` etc.)

Comment: I actually used Select Case first, and then found it easier to deal with it with If statements.  Thanks for the tip, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the OR statement, you must enter what you are trying to evaluate again.  So it should read

```
If UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JANUARY" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JAN" Then
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was so focused on the type mismatch being attributed to UCase that I completely missed that.  Thank you.